# Between 11pm and 7am in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to do a simple return function to check if it's between 11pm and 7am?

Had something like this in mind, but the problem with this is that 1am would be 1 and that wouldn't be greater than 23, but 23 (11pm) would be.

```
return (((new Date()).getHours() >= 23) && ((new Date()).getHours() <=7))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty close, but you should be using || not &&

```
var currentHour = (new Date()).getHours();
return (currentHour >= 23) || (currentHour <= 7);
```

If the hours are greater or equal to 23 (11pm) OR if hours is less than or equal to 7 (7am), then true it's between 11pm and 7am.

Noon, getHours() == 12, so then 12 >= 23 = false || 12 <= 7 = false, therefore return false;

Comment: what if 23:00 becomes 00:00?

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski I don't understanding what you mean

Comment: what if I want to check if it's between 12pm and 7am?

Comment: I suppose you could change the code to `(currentHour >= 12) || (currentHour <= 7)`

Comment: sorry, I mean 12am / 00:00.

Comment: What time is 00:00? I read that to be between 12am and 12am (00:00). His question was specific to 11pm and 7am, which I think my answer supports. But I am curious if there is a gap at times where my general method would fail.

Comment: Agree your answer is good to specific hours 11pm-7am. Doesn't suit other hours like 12am-7am. 00:00 is 1 minute after 23:59

Comment: `var x = new Date(2012, 1, 27, 23, 59, 0, 0); var y = new Date(); y.setTime(x.getTime() + 1000 * 60); y.getHours() // 0` So 23:59 + 1 minute is 12am, is 0. In that case the first part of the statement would be unnessary, so it would become `return currentHour <= 7'

Comment: Ok so what about `between 1am and 7am` etc.? You don't need to tell me what to do. What I mean it's always better to create global, bullet-proof solution for example function `is_hour_between($a,$b)` so it can suit all scenarios

Comment: [i mean just add few bytes more and you may create nice answer, which gonna work for other people too](https://gist.github.com/4647776)

Comment: Totally fair, I apologize. I thought you were hinting at some error in the logic for specific values. You're absolutely right creating a generalized function is usually the way to go for most things

Answer (score 0):

Fairly generic way to handle the problem ...

```
var inBetween = function(from, hour, to)
{
    if (from < to) return (hour >= from && hour < to);
    if (from > to) return !(hour >= to && hour < from);
    return !(from == to);
}

if (inBetween(21, (new Date()).getHours(), 7))
    // true
```