# Javascript time on a specific day between 2 times, then write open

Tags: javascript, if-statement, time, days

I am trying to write some javascript code for my website, that lets users know if we are open or not. For example,

On a Tuesday, if the time is between 09:00 and 18:30, then it would display OPEN, else CLOSED.

How do I do this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031410/javascript-if-time-is-between-7pm-and-7am-do-this

Answer (score 0):

I would do a switch statement on the opening time of each day, and check it for each one.

```
var day = (insert day);
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getHours() + date.getMinutes()/60;

switch(day) {
    case "Monday":
         break;
    case "Tuesday":
         if (time > 9 && time < 18.5) {
             // display open
             document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "OPEN";
         } else {
             // display closed
             document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "CLOSED";
         }
         break;
    case "Wednesday":
         break;
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Can you add an example for the // display open (i am a real noob at javascript coding!)

Comment: Thanks very much @david