# Time Based Links in HTML\JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on game right now that will have an Item Shop. I thought it would be fun that you couldn't just walk in at an untimely hour.

I made, with a bit of help, this random script (I'm not really sure if this will help) that will let you enter the shop 90% percent of the time. :

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
    var result = (Math.random()*10)
    var a = document.createElement('a');

if(result >= 9)
{
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("Enter The Shop");
    a.id = "OpenShop";
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    a.title = "A place to buy weapons and stuff!";
    a.href = "open.html";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    }
    else
    {
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("Don't Enter The Shop");
    a.id = "ClosedShop";
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    a.title = "A place to buy weapons and stuff!";
    a.href = "notopen.html";
    }  
    document.body.appendChild(a);
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to change a few lines and make it to where the shop could be open from 9 a.m.-8 p.m. but to be closed for the rest of the day.

(Before 9 a.m. and after 8 p.m. the shop needs to be closed.)

EDIT:
I am also unsure how to center this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031410/javascript-if-time-is-between-7pm-and-7am-do-this) asked by [Yanlu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648270/yanlu). In your case you would check if the current hour is at least 9 but less than 20.

Basing my answer on [Nev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860129/nev)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18031466/6506750), you should do:

```
var currentHours = new Date.getHours();
if (currentHours >= 9 && currentHours < 20) {
…
```

Comment: @DropTheChair Pretty much, see my updated answer for code. (Use < 20 if it closes at 8:00 or <= 20 if it's open through 8:59)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `new Date()` method. This creates a date like this: Sun Jun 26 2016 22:29:49 GMT+0200 (CEST); (Just like in the snippet below.)
Then you need to create an if statement. I would suggest the substring method so you can focus on the hours only.

```js
var currentdate = new Date();
var substringdate = currentdate.toString().substring(16,18);
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = substringdate;

if (substringdate > 07 && substringdate < 19) {
  document.getElementById("openedshop").style.opacity = "1";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("closedshop").style.opacity = "1";
    }

//use.toString because you can't use substring on numbers.
//I just used random conditions in the if statement, you can fill it in.
```

```css
a {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
<a href="#"id="openedshop">The shop</a> 
<a href="#"id="closedshop">The shop</a>
```

In this case, if the hour isn't equal to 22 then the shop is open. You can change this of course. Hope this helped!

Comment: If it is 7 i guess the time says 07 so you put in your if statement this: 'If (substringdate > 07)  { 
} else if (substringdate > 19) {

Comment: Right now the shop is open between 7 in the morning and 7 in the evening

Comment: Its okay, what do you mean with the links. And i will print it out.

Comment: Well actually if the time is between 7 in the morning and 7 in the evening (not now) than it gets printed out that the shop is open. It is already in the code

Comment: Oh okay. Maybe do something like when the time is between 7 in the morning and 7 in the evening that then a link s opacity will be 1 so you can click it otherwise you cant click it.

Comment: Haha alright basically add a link when the shop is closed, i'll update the code

Comment: Basically add your own link in the html, and now you see a link to the closed shop because the time is hours = 23 so it isn't like the conditions in the if statement so the else statement runs and that is link to closed shop. Tomorrow you will see a link to a opened store.

Comment: In the HTML where the href is. Right now it says: href="#" replace the # with your link.

Comment: I have edited it. The first a in the html is the link to the opened shop so there you put your link to the opened shop. The second a in the html is the link to the closed shop so there you put your link to the closed shop. When the shop is open, the link for the opened shop will be displayed (opacity = "1";) but when the shop is closed, the link for the closed shop will be displayed.

Comment: What do you mean? @DropTheChair

Comment: Well actually it is. I did this because otherwise both links would always be visible and this would mean that even when the shop is closed you can click both links and you access the store even if the store should be closed. You get it?

Comment: Maybe it will. You can set in the css the links to position: absolute; For if your not familiar with position: absolute; What it does is, it will stand where you margin'ed it. If you have an image. And then you have the links on position absolute, then they will stand above the image and they wont cause any problems with spacing. So it wont cause any problems with the spacing if you just add position: absolute; to the a in css.

Comment: Do you get it? @DropTheChair

Comment: I have edited the code, now the links have position: absolute; so it wont cause any problems with spacing.

Comment: And if you ever have questions, ask me!

Comment: Okay but can you vote up my answer, because then i will get at least 10 points for all my help.